# Dynamic row counter

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm trying to create a dynamic row number in *iReport*
Is there a way to create a variable that changes according to the following rules:

-increments according to row number

-stops incrementing if a field is of a certain type (e.g. XXX in the example below)

i.e.

------------------

s/n  FieldType  Amount  Cost

------------------

1     ZZZ           123         $34

2     YYY           111         $85

2     XXX           222         $24

3     YYY           111         $66

4     ZZZ           222         $75

5     ZZZ           555         $35

5     XXX           111         $14

6     ZZZ           888         $21

This is so that I can group XXX as part of the record before it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to do this. Create a new variable and change its class to Integer. Keep the default values for `resetType`, `incrementType`, and `calculation`; "Report", "None", and "Nothing", respectively.

Set the `initialValueExpression` to "1" (or whatever you want the first ID to be).

Set the `variableExpression` to:

```
$F{FieldType}.equals("XXX") ? $V{customID} : $V{customID} + 1
```

Where `customID` is the name of your new variable.

Comment: This worked! just that I had to put in stuff like new Integer(), intValue() etc. Just what I hate about Jasperreports...Thanks!